# Como atualizar a posicao do texto quando alterar a posicao do botao?

Tags: python, pygame

Tenho uma classe botao que e um sprite e tem como atributo text que tambem e um sprite. Eu queria saber como alterar a posicao do text quando eu mudar a posicao do rect do botao?

```
import pygame


class Botao(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/botao.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.text = Text(font["alfa_slab_one_40"], text, "#ffffff")


class Text(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, font, text, cor, fundo=None):
        self.image = font.render(text, True, cor, fundo)
        self.rect = self,image.get_rect()


botao = Botao("SIM")
botao.rect.center = self.tela_rect.center
```